# Como fazer a DIV preencher 100% do display?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Boa tarde

Gostaria de criar um site em que a altura da primeira DIV seja 100% do display exibido ao usuário, e quando dar o scroll, os demais elementos aparecem normalmente. 
Sei que tem uma forma de calcular isso usando jquery ou javascript.
Alguém sabe como faço isso?

Comment: não quero um menu, e sim toda a div ocupar o display

Comment: A melhor maneira de fazer isso é usando css mesmo

Answer (score 7):

Você pode usar o estilo `height: 100vh;`, que dá ao elemento a altura total do *viewport* (área visível da janela):

**Exemplo:**

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#primeira{
   background-color: yellow;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="primeira">
   Primeira div
</div>
<div>
   Segunda div
</div>
<div>
   Terceira div
</div>
```

### Usando `height: 100%`

Para que a `div` tenha a mesma altura do *viewport* usando porcentagem (`%`), é preciso definir o `html` e o `body` em `100%`.

```css
html, body{
   margin: 0;
   height: 100%;
}

#primeira{
   background-color: yellow;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="primeira">
   Primeira div
</div>
<div>
   Segunda div
</div>
<div>
   Terceira div
</div>
```

### Usando JavaScript

Pode usar o `window.innerHeight` para pegar a altura do *viewport* e atribuir ao `height` da primeira `div`. Exemplo:

```js
var el = document.body.querySelector("#primeira");

function altura(){
   el.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", altura);
window.addEventListener("resize", altura);
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#primeira{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="primeira">
   Primeira div
</div>
<div>
   Segunda div
</div>
<div>
   Terceira div
</div>
```

Em **jQuery** seria:

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   $("#primeira").css("height",window.innerHeight+"px");
});
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#primeira{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="primeira">
   Primeira div
</div>
<div>
   Segunda div
</div>
<div>
   Terceira div
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito, só queria saber se tem como ele ir diminuindo junto a medida que eu reduzir a janela. No momento ele só se adapta novamente se eu der um reload na página.

Comment: Vc diz no caso do javascript?

Answer (score 0):

## 1 - Definindo as tags `html` e `body` com `height:100%;`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
div.foo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(220, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="foo">
  Tela completa
 </div>
 <div>
  Abaixo da tela completa
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## 2 - Definindo `position: absolute;` para a tag `body`:

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
div.foo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(220, 50, 50);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="foo">
  Tela completa
 </div>
 <div>
  Abaixo da tela completa
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> [How can I make a div 100% of window height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609531/how-can-i-make-a-div-100-of-window-height)

Answer (score 0):

A opacidade é bonus :)

```css
*{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
#suadiv{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:11;
 background-color:#0000ff;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 opacity: .50;
 filter: alpha(opacity=65);
}
```

```html
<div id="suadiv"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `$(window).resize();` veja que a `<DIV>` é ajustada ao modificar o tamanho da tela.

```js
$(window).on("load resize", function(){
   $("#primeira").css("height",window.innerHeight+"px");
});
$(window).resize(function() {
   var calHeight = $(window).height()*0.798;
   $('#primeira').fullCalendar('option', 'height', calHeight);
});
```

```css
body{
   margin: 0;
}

#primeira{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="primeira">
   Primeira div
</div>
<div>
   Segunda div
</div>
<div>
   Terceira div
</div>
```

Boa sorte!